# Assign the trim_lasso_gesture operator to a custom panel

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, sculpt-mode

I am currently working on an addon that should provide the user with different build in operators of Blender via a custom user interface. For this I need a panel, where the user can use the operator *Lasso Trim* (bpy.ops.sculpt.trim_lasso_gesture()) only by clicking on the panel. The operator should be assigned to a panel as it is and it does not need any new functions. When the user has selected an object in the viewport, he can click on the panel and use "Lasso Trim" to trim the object. The only thing that is a bit "special" about it is that the panel has to switch to sculpt mode automatically. After using the lasso trim, the panel should automatically switch back to object mode. Unfortunately, I am not getting anywhere with this. I have tried different things but my result is still super buggy. Just so this is not misunderstood: the *trim_lasso_gesture*
operator during trimming should behave exactly the same as it does in Sculpt-Mode. It should just be more easily accessible for the user via the extra panel.

I would be very grateful for any help!

```
import bpy

class ModalOperatorEraser(bpy.types.Operator):
   """Erase something"""
   bl_idname = "sculpt.modal_operator_eraser"
   bl_label = "Simple Eraser Tool"
   
   

   def invoke(self,context, event):
       scene = context.scene
       obj = context.active_object
       bpy.ops.sculpt.sculptmode_toggle()
       context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)

       return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
   
   def modal(self, context, event): 
       bpy.ops.sculpt.trim_lasso_gesture("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
       if event.type == 'ESC':
           bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
           return {'FINISHED'}
       
       return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
       

class EraserPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
   bl_idname = "ERASER_Panel"
   bl_label = "Eraser"
   bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
   bl_region_type = "UI"
   bl_category = "Eraser"

   def draw(self, context):
       layout = self.layout
       row = layout.row()
       row.operator("sculpt.modal_operator_eraser", text="Eraser")
       
       
def register():
   bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperatorEraser)
   bpy.utils.register_class(EraserPanel)
   
def unregister():
   bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperatorEraser)
   bpy.utils.unregister_class(EraserPanel)
       
               
if __name__ == "__main__":
   register()
```

Comment: `Unfortunately, I am not getting anywhere with this. I have tried different things but my result is still super buggy.` Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Okay, I think I found the problem: with `def modal` I had to add
`if event.type == "LEFTMOUSE":      bpy.ops.sculpt.trim_lasso_gesture("INVOKE_DEFAULT")`
so far blender always crashed as soon as i wanted to end the operator. also the cursor started to trim when i clicked the panel button. I was also confused by the lack of the typical circles around the cursor that are usually found with the brushes.

Comment: cool, I would write this into an answer if I were you.

Comment: Okay, after some testing i found a bug: if you click after selecting the panel without creating a path with the curser, belender crashes. unfortunately the problem is not solved yet.